# Input field must accept only 5 commas maximum in jquery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Is there any validation in jquery that accepts only 5 commas but i can use any numbers of other letters in the input field or it shows inline error as "only 5 commas allowed" on submit.please any one give me a solution for this and i am searching for this a whole day.thank you

Comment: you can do it manually through JS regex, the inline error can be implemented through a hidden div that is shown when the input changes  (or the input focus is lost) and there is more than 5 commas

Comment: getting the right JS regex is the hard part here!

Comment: it's not that hard, just post your trial and we will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [jQuery Validation Plugin](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation), this is how to create a custom rule to check the commas:

**JS:**

```
$.validator.addMethod("comma-rule", function(value){
    var n = value.split(",").length - 1;
    return (n <= 5);
}, "Only 5 commas allowed");

$("form").validate({
    rules: {
        "commas-input": "comma-rule"
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<form>
    <input type='text' name='commas-input' />
</form>
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/5RrGa/1473/

Answer (score 1):

You could use split() on commas and validate the array returned is not greater than 6 in length.

I say 6 because 5 commas would give you a 6 item array.

Comment: It does exactly what you want, any number of any other character, but only 5 commas. Any more than 5 commas, it will fail.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validStr (str) {
 var exit = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length ; i++) {
  if(str.charAt(i) == ",")
   exit++;
 };
 if (exit > 5){
  return false;
 }else{
  return true;
 }
}
```

try this

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `input` event , `String.prototype.match()`

```js
var input = document.querySelector("input[type=text]")
, label = document.querySelector("[for=input]")
, lim = function lim(e) {
  label.textContent = "";
  if (e.target.value.match(/,/g).length > 5) {        
      e.target.value = e.target.value.replace(/,$/, "");
      label.textContent = "only 5 commas allowed";
  };
};
input.oninput = lim;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" />
<label for="input"></label>
```

Comment: yours doesn't work if we copy paste more than 10 commas

Comment: still copy pasting allows more than 5 commas

Comment: @newman _"still copy pasting allows more than 5 commas"_ See updated post.

Comment: thanks working well but he came first with what i wanted...thanks again